# Pulumi always marking helm chart as needing update due to checksum difference

Tags: kubernetes-helm, pulumi, istio-kiali

Even though no changes are being applied to related helm chart or values pulumi keeps marking `kiali/server` as always needing to be updated due to checksum:

```
    ~   kubernetes:helm.sh/v3:Release  foo:istio-system:kiali-server  update  [diff: ~checksum]
```

If I check plan details it's always the same checksum issue:

```
      ~ checksum: "850XXXX2" => "14eXXXXa59"
```